# How to inject Javascript in the WP7 WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I can inject JavaScript in WebBrowser control in C# windows form by this link

[How to inject JavaScript in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control)

But I can't do this in WP7, please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately `WebBrowser.Document` is not available on WP7. But you can create and call a JavaScript function using `InvokeScript`. Have a look [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317917/56658) where I describe how.

In short: you don't use `.Document` and C# but create a piece of JavaScript instead. You then call `eval` with this script as parameter to invoke it. Like this:

```
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "  ...code goes here... ");
```

Comment: but some pages may not contains **eval** function

Comment: @Heinrich Ulbricht I have tried your solution but it does not work in my case. I was wondering if you could help? I have javascript code from http://www.liveside.net/2011/10/21/tip-how-to-get-forward-and-find-on-page-back-in-ie9-mobile-on-windows-phone-7-5/ Find On Page option and can not seem to properly insert it into the InvokeScript function. I am getting Error: 80020101 SystemException unhandled.

Comment: @Matthew Try sending in your code with quotationmarks. eg. webBrowser1.InvokeScript("\" ... code goes here... \"");

Comment: @sma6871 **eval** is a built-in JavaScript function and always available, regardless of a webpage's content.

Comment: @TomLint, what about a basic page like this: `<body></body>`? With this one, `eval` sure does *not* work with a desktop `WebBrowser`, at least one `<script>` tag is required. Do you reckon it is not required for for Windows Phone?

Comment: @Noseratio InvokeScript directly invokes the built-in javascript parser of the webbrowser to execute the specified javascript, there is no need for any <script> tags in the shown case.

Comment: @TomLint, my point is correct at least for IE on Windows Desktop, try it for a page without `<script>` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For desktop `WebBrowser` (WinForms/WPF), at least one `<script>` tag has to be present on the web page for `InvokeScript("eval", ...)` to work. I.e., if the page doesn't contain any JavaScript (e.g. `<body></body>`), `eval` doesn't work as is.

I don't have Windows Phone SDK/emulator installed to verify if this is also the case with Windows Phone `WebBrowser`.

Nevertheless, the following works for a Windows Store App. The trick is to use `this.webBrowser.InvokeScript("setTimeout", ...)` to inject some JavaScript first. I'm using it instead of [`execScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is deprecated since IE11.

```
async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // load a blank page
    var tcsLoad = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    this.webBrowser.NavigationCompleted += (s, eArgs) =>
        tcsLoad.TrySetResult(Type.Missing);
    this.webBrowser.NavigateToString("<body></body>");
    await tcsLoad.Task;

    // first add a script via "setTimeout", JavaScript gets initialized
    var tcsInit = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    this.webBrowser.ScriptNotify += (s, eArgs) =>
    {
        if (eArgs.Value == "initialized")
            tcsInit.TrySetResult(Type.Missing);
    };
    this.webBrowser.InvokeScript("setTimeout", 
        new string[] { "window.external.notify('initialized')", "0" });
    await tcsInit.Task;

    // then use "eval"
    this.webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", 
        new string[] { "document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'" });
}
```

I would appreciate if someone can confirm whether this works or not for WP `WebBrowser`. [`LoadCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) should be used for WP instead of `NavigationCompleted` in the code above, and [`WebBrowser.IsScriptEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) has to be set to `true`.

Comment: From my early investigations the settimeout hack does seem to work also for the WPF WebBrowser Control with IE11. Actually calling InvokeScript("settimeout", "ANYFUNCTIONHERE") causes JavaScript to be activated on the page and thus subsequent eval calls also appear to work.

Comment: @jpierson, I did test the `setTimeout` trick for the Desktop and Windows Store apps, but I did not for Windows Phone, which is what's this question is about.