# Inject/serve custom CSS in WP8 WebBrowser Control

Tags: webbrowser-control, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to inject Javascript in the WP7 WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348503/how-to-inject-javascript-in-the-wp7-webbrowser-control)

I have a WebBrowser control in my MainPage.xaml serving an external web page.

```
<phone:WebBrowser 
    Name="TravelPlanner" 
    Source="http://URL-HERE.com" 
    IsScriptEnabled="True"/>
```

Is it possible for me to somehow inject or serve my own CSS (or JavaScript for that matter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. By invoking [WebBrowser.InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402855%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) after [WebBrowser.LoadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you can execute arbitrary javascript code in a webbrowser control. Web apps can then use [WebBrowser.ScriptNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.scriptnotify%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to talk back to C#.

See more @ [How to inject Javascript in the WP7 WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348503/how-to-inject-javascript-in-the-wp7-webbrowser-control)