# How can I change a webpage's background and foreground color in a web browser element?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, browser

In my application I am rendering some HTML pages into a `WebBrowser` element. In some articles I found that the WebBrowser's background as well as foreground colors depend on the HTML page properties.

How could I change this HTML background and foreground color in my program to view a custom color ?

Comment: Inject CSS. See this for further details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113311/inject-serve-custom-css-in-wp8-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `InvokeScript` method of the `WebBrowser` control to inject some Javascript code that will in turn change element properties like background and foreground colors.

Sample code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.webBrowser1.IsScriptEnabled = true;
    this.webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://yourpage.com/"));
    this.webBrowser1.LoadCompleted += webBrowser1_LoadCompleted;
}

void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { "document.body.style.background = 'black';" });
}
```

Comment: got this exception "An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020006."

Comment: friend above exception i got when come used this code

Comment: @PradeepKesharwani, not sure about WP `WebBrowser`, but for the Desktop one, there has to be at least one `<script>` element on the currently loaded page for `InvokeScript("eval")` to work.