# Can I inject JavaScript object into WebBrowser?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, browser

I need to inject a js file with a class into WebBrowser element for WP7 application, but I get an unknown runtime error:

```
 webbrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "function Player() {  this.play = function(e) { window.external.notify(e); }}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Describe your error. You can find it in your IDE. I once encountered with a js inject error because I tried to inject it before the webbrowser is ready. Be sure to place your code in the webbrowser's documentReady() callback

Comment: There is no documentReady() callback in Windows Phone WebBrowser, but the error seems to be gone when I put this code into Navigated callback. There are no errors now. But it is not working...

Comment: Duplicate: [How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348503/how-to-inject-javascript-in-the-wp7-webbrowser-control)

Comment: I have to confess I haven't tried WP. However things are similar with c# winform. And Navigated() is called after successfully loading the document.

Comment: Alla Masoud, it is not a duplicate. This problem is more specific than the one you've pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered this myself.

The problem is that you are not sending in the parameter as a string.
eval takes a string as parameter and if you invoke this script with your current parameter it will translate into:

```
eval(function Player() {  this.play = function(e) { window.external.notify(e); }})
```

when what you really want to do is:

```
eval("function Player() {  this.play = function(e) { window.external.notify(e); }}")
```

So the correct this, try:

```
webbrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "\"function Player() {  this.play = function(e) { window.external.notify(e); }}\"");
```