# C# with HTML forms

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Am developing a windows phone app using C#.
There is a web browser displaying  HTML form containing radio buttons.
Is there any way of getting the selected button value to be used in C# and based on that selected button value, I can decide which events has to be occurred further.

Comment: Are you using HTML as a method to build your GUI?

Comment: No.Am using XAML.Browser displays data taken from a server

Comment: Do you control the web page as well? Or is this something external?

Comment: I just display a static webpage.

Comment: Right, but is that a webpage you have the ability to modify?

Comment: No.It has a from containing a group of items and only one of them is to be selected and the item selected must be known out of HTML to C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate between an html page and C# code using JavaScript. In fact, you can inject a js into your HTML page to retrieve the selected item, and pass the parameter back to a C# callback. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8349343/1279761) for more information.