# Inject JS script in the browser of Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have a page with a web browser control within a WP 8.1 app. Is there a way to inject a JS script when open a page with it. I have the JavaScript file in my solution dir, and I'll read it like a string maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily inject JS script to document. Look at these links:

[How to inject Javascript in the WP7 WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348503/how-to-inject-javascript-in-the-wp7-webbrowser-control/22372934#22372934)

http://www.jayway.com/2014/03/10/windows-phone-8-native-and-javascript-interop/

If you have your script in solution you can load it and inject to browser.

Comment: These links are for WP7 and WP8, but not WP8.1

Comment: Yes but API is very simillar in WP8.1 for Windows Runtime. InvokeScript is still available. Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx