# How do I invoke an SMS compose from a website on Windows Phone 7.5?

Tags: windows-phone-7, web, sms

This is dead easy for iOS, Android and even BlackBerry OS by just using the `sms:` prefix in your href attribute, like so:

```
<a href="sms:0046730123456">Send an SMS to +46 73 012 34 56</a>
```

This launches the SMS application with the number pre-filled on previously mentioned platforms. But on WP7.5 using Internet Explorer, we get an error saying that the URL scheme is not supported. Someone online hinted at `smsto:` but that didn't work either.

Comment: what about `<a href="sms://0046730123456">` ?

Comment: Does not work, I'm afraid. The other browsers just adds the double slashes to the phone number.

Comment: @FredrikFrodlund Did you ever find a solution? Dealing with a similar problem with SMS links on Windows Phone.

Comment: @mapr I completely missed your comment for over 1,5 years. Sorry about that :/ I'm afraid I never found a solution to the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the javascript inject to get the link click event,  the solution is like [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317697/is-it-possible-to-detect-the-dom-element-tapped-in-a-wp7-webbrowser-control/8317917#8317917)

Comment: I'm not sure what I would accomplish with this. How is this different from a regular anchor click? Mind you, we got tel: working just fine on IE in WP7.5.

Comment: @FredrikFrodlund  to make things much simpler, you can look into the navigating event of the webbrowser,  then you can use "string url = e.Uri.ToString();", according to the url, you can judge if the click is cause by the "href="sms..."".

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get how this applies. The basic problem still lies with WP7 not understanding the sms: url scheme. Am I missing something? :/